# Como hago para que al presionar la tecla ESC el ciclo cierre en lenguaje Masm ensamblador?

Tags: ensamblador

Esta es la parte de condigo que llevo el programa tiene que pedir un carácter por pantalla y el ciclo while debe cerrarse cuando presionemos la tecla ESC

```
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax

@@while:

    mov dx,OFFSET titulo; mardar 
    mov ah, 9h;
    int 21h; interrupcion

    mov ah,01h;
    int 21h

    cmp cont,19
    jnl finwhile 
  
    jmp @@while

    finwhile:
    
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
```

.EXIT ;DIRECTIVA donde terminará el ensablador
END

Answer (score 0):

No tengo mucha idea de ensamblador, pero mirando un poco he encontrado en un foro un programa en ensamblador que escribe la letra "X" hasta que presiones la tecla ESC.

Te pongo aquí el código, el enlace del foro y un enlace a unos ejercicios resueltos donde se encuentra entre otros este que voy a publicar.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

**FORO**:

https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/Ensamblador/5767-Escribir-la-letra-X-hasta-que-se-presione-ESC.html

**EJERCICIOS RESUELTOS**:

https://www.programacion.com.py/escritorio/ensamblador/ejercicios-resueltos-en-ensamblador-8086

**CÓDIGO**:

```
name "keybrd"
org 100h
; print a welcome message:
mov dx, offset msg
mov ah, 9
int 21h
;============================
; eternal loop to get
; and print keys:
wait_for_key:
; check for keystroke in
; keyboard buffer:
mov dh, pos
 mov dl, pos
 mov bh, 0
 mov ah, 2
 int 10h ;Movemos el cursor
 mov al,'X'
 mov bh,0
 mov bl,1
 mov cx,1
 mov ah,09h
 inc pos ;Imprimimos una x
 int 10h
 mov ah, 1
 int 16h
 jz wait_for_key
; get keystroke from keyboard:
; (remove from the buffer)
mov ah, 0
int 16h
; print the key:
mov ah, 0eh
int 10h
; press 'esc' to exit:
cmp al, 1bh
jz exit
jmp wait_for_key
;============================
exit:
ret
msg db "Type anything...", 0Dh,0Ah
 db "[Enter] - carriage return.", 0Dh,0Ah
 db "[Ctrl]+[Enter] - line feed.", 0Dh,0Ah
 db "You may hear a beep", 0Dh,0Ah
 db " when buffer is overflown.", 0Dh,0Ah
 db "Press Esc to exit.", 0Dh,0Ah, "$"
pos db 1
end
```